# Why am I getting a <function> is not a member of <class>? I was trying to pass a string and return from it

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am trying to pass a string to a function, which is going to be sorted. Then to have the sorted string to be return from it. It won't compile, and it even says that "binarySort is not a member of Others".

Is it something that's not allowed to do?

This is the Class File

```
#include "Others.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char Others::inputCheck(char guess) {
    while (!isalpha(guess)) { //If the inputs are not alphabets, keep looping.
        cout << "Enter again: ";
        cin >> guess;
    }
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    guess = tolower(guess);

    return guess;
}

string Others::binarySort(string sampleText) {
    //Bubble sorting the string. (Copy pasted)
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleText.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sampleText.length(); j++)
        {
            if (sampleText[i] > sampleText[j]) //if previous has bigger ascii value than next,
            {
                //swapping the prev and next characters
                char temp = sampleText[i];
                sampleText[i] = sampleText[j];
                sampleText[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return sampleText;
}
```

This is the Header File.

```
#ifndef OTHERS_HEADER
#define OTHERS_HEADER
#pragma once
class Others
{
public:
    char inputCheck(char guess); //Function to check if inputs are alphabets.
    string binarySort(string sampleText);
};

#endif
```

The main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Others.h"

using namespace std;
int main() {
    string sortedText, sampleText = "toibeawn";
    Others sorter;
    sortedText = sorter.binarySort(sampleText);
    cout << "Text after sorted:\n";
    cout << sortedText;

    return 0;
}
```

The sort works if it's not used for a function.

The error output:

1>Sorting_test.cpp
1>Others.cpp
1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\Others.h(9,7): error C2039: 'string': is not a member of 'std'

1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(368): message : see declaration of 'std'

1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\Others.h(9,24): error C3646: 'binarySort': unknown override specifier

1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\Others.h(9,24): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\Others.h(9,30): error C2039: 'string': is not a member of 'std'

1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(368): message : see declaration of 'std'

1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\Others.h(9,48): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\Others.cpp(16,21): error C2039: 'binarySort': is not a member of 'Others'

1>C:\Users\yap_2\source\repos\Sorting\Sorting_test\Others.h(5): message : see declaration of 'Others'
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "Sorting_test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: Your program looks good, are you keeping all related files in same project or in same directory(depends on your IDE)? It is something related to your build environment.

Comment: All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links and images removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that include everything as plain text, and I see no reason why this question one can't, either.

Comment: You can copy the compilation errors from the "output" tab.  Pay attention to the first error:  it reports the first error it finds, and in this case it is because you're missing a necessary header in others.h.

Comment: steephen, yes, everything is in one directory and I using Visual Studio Community 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include "Others.h" prior to declaring `using namespace std` which results in `string` being unrecognized in the included header.

Add `using namespace std;` in the header "Others.h" and the error will be gone.

Generally, it is a bad practice to have `using namespace std` in headers and you'd better just write `std::string`.

Comment: i've removed all of the namespaces, but it's not compiling.

Comment: @Fluxcuate don't forget that `std::string` is defined in a header file while "Others.h" doesn't have one included that defines it. Include it via `#include <string>`

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. Require changes a simple change.

- in your header include this header :  #include  and use std namespace.

So after changes, your header looks like

```
#ifndef OTHERS_HEADER
#define OTHERS_HEADER
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

The main problem is, in your header the string is not resolved due to the lake of string header and std namespace.

Note: Always try to include language headers first and then your custom headers.

Comment: `string` is not defined in the `<iostream>` header, so that is the wrong one to include.

Comment: Yes, correct, string header need to be included. .corrected the answer.

Comment: I removed all of the "using namespace std" from all of the files and used the "std::" instead. But it didn't work. Just like ALX23z suggested, and I didn't try to add the "namespace std" to the header file since he said that it is a bad practice.
After tried adding "using namespace std" and <iostream> it works.

Comment: @Fluxcuate iostream is added on both class implementation file and main file but only lacking is string header and namespace.  Quick fix also can be just adding <iostream> header on class header file and also include namespace std in same file will solve the issue .

Answer (score 0):

`std::string binarySort(std::string sampleText)`

Needed a namespace